# Mask @ character in SAS RegEX

Tags: sas

The `@` character (in bold)  in the replacement string of my RegEx s/<<[\w|+|@|#]+>>/\s*(<<[\w|\+|#**|@**]+>>)\s*/ is causing an error. When I replace the RegEx with s/<<[\w|+|@|#]+>>/\s*(<<[\w|\+|#]+>>)\s*/, the error goes away.

How do I mask the `@` character. `%NRSTR` does not seem to work.

CODE:

```
Data _NULL_;
    a=prxchange(%NRSTR("s/<<[\w|\+|@|#]+>>/\s*(<<[\\w|\\+|#|@]+>>)\s*/"), -1, "<<A>> <<A+>> <<A@>> <<A@+>> <<A#>> <<A#+>>");
    putlog a;
run;
```

LOG:

```
ERROR: An array reference was found in replacement text

       "s/<<[\w|\+|@|#]+>>/\s*(<<[\\w|\\+|#|@]+>>)\s*/". Array references within replacement text

       are not supported.

ERROR: The regular expression passed to the function PRXCHANGE contains a syntax error.

NOTE: Argument 1 to function PRXCHANGE('s/<<[\w|\+|@'[12 of 46 characters shown],-1,'<<WORD>>

      <<W'[12 of 60 characters shown]) at line 1656 column 3 is invalid.



a=  _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
```

Comment: Regarding `[\w|\+|@|#]`. Are you sure character classes `[]` require alternation `|` ?  Did you mean to have a capture group `()` instead of character class `[]` ?

Comment: It is a simplified version of the code i am trying to build. The pattern should match things like `WORD+` or `WORD@+` so the alternation is required. I initially had capture groups but it did not seem to help.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and results desired ?

Comment: @ is not a special character to the macro processor. So macro quoting is not going to do anything.

Comment: Did you just try adding \ prefix to escape it?

Comment: @Tom Single quotes are the first thing i tried. And yes, you are right, it does not seem to be a macro quoting problem.  I am just not sure if there is a function that will mask the `@` since the code seem to be perfectly fine without the `@`

Comment: @Richard I can provide you with an example but I am not looking for a workaround on how to do it. I am more curious on why the error is occurring. I am specifically looking into how to mask the `@`.

Comment: I can get it to run by just changing `@` to `\@`, but since you didn't show what result you expected I can't tell if it is actually working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?  I added escape character before the ampersands.

```
data _null_;
  length regex in out $200 ;
  regex='s/<<[\w|\+|\@|#]+>>/\s*(<<[\\w|\\+|#|\@]+>>)\s*/';
  in = '<<A>> <<A+>> <<A@>> <<A@+>> <<A#>> <<A#+>>';
  out=prxchange(regex,-1,in);
  putlog (_all_) (//= :$quote.);
run;
```

Results:

```
regex="s/<<[\w|\+|\@|#]+>>/\s*(<<[\\w|\\+|#|\@]+>>)\s*/"

in="<<A>> <<A+>> <<A@>> <<A@+>> <<A#>> <<A#+>>"

out="s*(<<[\w|\+|#|@]+>>)s* s*(<<[\w|\+|#|@]+>>)s* s*(<<[\w|\+|#|@]+>>)s* s*(<<[\w|\+|#|@]+>>)s* s*(<<[\w|\
+|#|@]+>>)s* s*(<<[\w|\+|#|@]+>>)s*"
```

Comment: Good one! `@` is not on the list of characters to be escaped on the SAS regex cheatsheet. https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/perl_regexp/regexp-tip-sheet.pdf